# GPA Calculator help in C

Tags: c

I am currently in the process of learning C and one of the challenge questions at the end of a chapter has me building a GPA Calculator.  Here is the Challenge:

> Create a student GPA average calculator.  The program should prompt the user to enter up to 30 GPAs, which are stored in a single-dimension array.  Each time he or she enters a GPA, the user should have the option to calculate the current GPA average or enter another GPA.  Sample data for this program:
>
> `GPA: 3.5`
>     `GPA: 2.8`
>     `GPA: 3.0`
>     `GPA: 2.5`
>
> Hint: Be careful to not calculate empty array elements into your student GPA average.

I have the program appear to somewhat work but when it calculates the GPA average it calculates wrong.  Will someone please take a look at my source code and let me know what I did wrong?

Source Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    float fGrades[30] = {0};
    float fAverage = 0;
    int x;
    int y = 0;
    float fSum = 0;
    char cResp = '\0';

    printf("\nGPA Calculater");
    printf("\nYou can enter up to 30 grades");
        
    do 
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a grade and press enter: ");
        scanf("%f", &fGrades[x]);

        printf("\nDo you want to calculate the GPA? (Y or N): ");
        scanf("\n%c", &cResp);
        
    } while (x < 30 && cResp != 'Y' && cResp != 'y');//end do while loop

    for (x = 0; x < 30; x++) 
    {
        fSum += fGrades[x];
    }//end for loop

    fAverage = fSum / x;

    printf("\nYour final GPA is: %.2f\n", fAverage);
    return 0;
}//end main function
```

Output I get is as follows:

```
GPA Calculater
You can enter up to 30 grades
Please enter a grade and press enter: 3.22

Do you want to calculate the GPA? (Y or N): n

Please enter a grade and press enter: 3.13

Do you want to calculate the GPA? (Y or N): n

Please enter a grade and press enter: 2.89

Do you want to calculate the GPA? (Y or N): n

Please enter a grade and press enter: 3.05

Do you want to calculate the GPA? (Y or N): y

Your final GPA is: 0.10
```

Comment: you're always assuming there are 30 grades. on the line `fAverage = fSum / x;` x is always 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you always sum up 30 elements **no matter what**.

You should only add as many items that have been entered by the user.

So something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

float fGrades[30] = {0};
float fAverage = 0;
int x;
int y = 0;
int counter = 0;
float fSum = 0;
char cResp = '\0';

printf("\nGPA Calculater");
printf("\nYou can enter up to 30 grades");

do 
{
    printf("\nPlease enter a grade and press enter: ");
    scanf("%f", &fGrades[counter]);
    counter++;

    printf("\nDo you want to calculate the GPA? (Y or N): ");
    scanf("\n%c", &cResp);

} while (counter < 30 && cResp != 'Y' && cResp != 'y');//end do while loop

for (x = 0; x < counter; x++) 
{
    fSum += fGrades[x];
}//end for loop

fAverage = fSum / x;

printf("\nYour final GPA is: %.2f\n", fAverage);
return 0;
}//end main function
```

Comment: you probably want `&fGrades[counter]`

Comment: you're while condition is still x depended instead of counter 
`} while (x < 30 && cResp != 'Y' && cResp != 'y');//end do while loop`

Comment: Thanks Mate!  I ended up doing the following:

- adding an increment to x after the `scanf`
- changing the sum for loop to y
    `for (y = 0; y <= x; y++) `
 `{`
  `fSum += fGrades[y];`
 `}//end for loop`
- changed my `printf` that lets the user know what was entered to only show the values entered.

Comment: Also make sure to handle the divide by zero case

Comment: It is never the case that we divide by zero. We always ask for at least one grade.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to suggest:

- initialize `x` to 0
- in the initial do/while loop, increment `x` after you have scanf'd in the array
- in the loop that calculates `fSum`, use another counter and go from `counter = 0; counter < x; ++counter` and use `fSum += fGrades[counter];`.

Answer (score 0):

change the loop that calculated fSum to work with another variable instead of x

```
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < x; i++) 
{
    fSum += fGrades[ i ];
}//end for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems
1) x is not initialized, so scanf in do-while may crash your code
2) x in not incremented in do-while
3) while calculating average, you should sum only entered values, not all 30 values, else your average calculation will be wrong

Modified code as below, please check

```
int main() 
{

float fGrades[30] = {0};
float fAverage = 0;
int x;
int y = 0;
float fSum = 0;
char cResp = '\0';

printf("\nGPA Calculater");
printf("\nYou can enter up to 30 grades");
x = 0;
do 
{
    printf("\nPlease enter a grade and press enter: ");
    scanf("%f", &fGrades[x]);

    printf("\nDo you want to calculate the GPA? (Y or N): ");
    scanf("\n%c", &cResp);
    x++;
} while (x < 30 && cResp != 'Y' && cResp != 'y');//end do while loop

for (y = 0; y < x; y++) 
{
    fSum += fGrades[y];
}//end for loop

fAverage = fSum / x;

printf("\nYour final GPA is: %.2f\n", fAverage);
return 0;
}//end main function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 'for' loop to calculate the sum of all values. You can calculate the sum into the 'do while' loop. It will make your code more efficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

float fGrades[30] = {0};
float fAverage = 0;
int x;
int y = 0;
float fSum = 0;
char cResp = '\0';
int count = 0;

printf("\nGPA Calculater");
printf("\nYou can enter up to 30 grades");

do 
{
    printf("\nPlease enter a grade and press enter: ");
    scanf("%f", &fGrades[x]);
    fSum += fGrades[x];
    count++;

    printf("\nDo you want to calculate the GPA? (Y or N): ");
    scanf("\n%c", &cResp);

} while (x < 30 && cResp != 'Y' && cResp != 'y');//end do while loop

fAverage = fSum / count;

printf("\nYour final GPA is: %.2f\n", fAverage);
return 0;
}//end main function
```